Does an activated carbon filter on air intake do anything on a high mileage vehicle?
My wife's Toyota Camry has a permanent activated carbon filter attached to the air manifold that contains the air intake filter. The technical part which contains this carbon filter on my wife's 2011 Toyota Camry is the Air Cleaner Cover Assembly (currently 17705-31271 which replaces 17705-31160 and 17705-31270).
You can see the fixed carbon filter inside the Cover Assembly held next to the air filter in this video by Scotty Kilmer The Great. The video is otherwise unrelated to this post, but included to source the screengrab.

Surely this carbon does something beneficial when the vehicle is new, but activated carbon doesn't function forever. Is there any purpose in this air obstruction when the vehicle has 100,000 miles?
I am not asking about the benefits of removing this filter, only the detriments. But for completeness there are lots of claims about this filter cost MPG, torque, and horsepower -- like in this video. So much so that Engineering Explained even quantified these effects finding it made a vehicle made 4.14% more performant with the stock filter after the removal of the permanent carbon filter.

Just to be clear, I am not interested in the benefits of this removal, nor the legal implications. Is there any technical reason to keep this filter in place in a high mileage vehicle, or is the carbon filter just an inert obstruction after 100,000 miles or so? Can we just remove it entirely or are there technical drawbacks to removing it?

There are two parts I'm aware of which may have activated carbon in them: the vapor canister; cabin air filter. Neither of these are in the air intake system. Could you provide a more detailed description and maybe an image reference to what you're talking about?

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 happy to explain more, thanks for the comment. ;) Do the clarifications help explain what I'm talking about, why people are doing it, and why I want more information about the detriments of this if I choose to do it myself?

Also upvotes appreciated if this satisfies your idea of a good question now. ;)

It seems to me this would be pretty much useless for anything besides creating a larger obstruction in the air path. To my line of reasoning, there is absolutely no need for there to be activated carbon in the path of the air intake. The only reason why they put it into the cabin air filter is to help the air smell fresher. I'm pretty much thinking the engine doesn't care ... at all.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 there was one claim somewhere that it was supposed to stop gas vapors from returning to the throttle body and depositing carbon residue. I also saw a claim that there was environmental reason. Maybe the charcoal has a magical effect on unburned fuel returning through the air intake? But I can't see an environmental reason that would justify a 1-4% loss in performance. I no confidence in either of these theories. Seemed like a good question for the site anyway, even if we both intuitively respond with "I can't think of any reason for this".

The problem with the "gas vapors" theory is, the PCV draws vacuum after the throttle body ... the crankcase fumes wouldn't go through the filter, therefore no benefit in that case.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'm just pasting things I read, here is another similar theory from Reddit, https://www.reddit.com/r/Toyota/comments/1dbzsnb/comment/l7vmh2t/

If you review the video from Engineering Explained, a minute into the video explains the activated charcoal is part of emissions controls; to capture residual fuel vapors and crankcase gases in the intake manifold from escaping out the air intake snorkel when the engine is shut down. Some states may or may not inspect the air intake filter assembly to determine if the charcoal filter was removed, grounds for immediate emissions failure. Two things to keep in mind with this charcoal filter; does your state perform emissions inspection and check for this filter?

Also, the image taken from the Scotty Kilmer video appears to show a pre-filter, not a charcoal filter. The pre-filter would be there to catch larger bits/pieces and help the main filter to last longer.
